# Grails multiple database without hibernate

Tags: hibernate, grails, datasource

I want to ask, how to running 2 database in grails without hibernate?

example i have call 2 db in my datasource :

db1 and db2

and i have 2 domain in my app,

```
class domain1 {
   ...
   static mapping = {
      datasource 'db1'
   }
}

class domain2 {
   ...
   static mapping = {
      datasource 'db2'
   }
}
```

when i'm still in hibernate, everthing was okay, 
but when i uninstall hibernate i get error, my domain2 don't get db2,
what i miss? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need hibernate (or some counterpart like mongodb gorm) to support default Gorm functions.

Comment: okay, so if i don't use hibernate, is possible to run 2 database? thanks

Comment: well... without hibernate(or some counterpart like mongo gorm), you can access dbs through jdbc or something lower level apis like that, but the db can not be mapped to domain classes automatically.